# Outlook VBA Rules Apply to All Messages and Mark as Read

Tags: vba, outlook, rules

I am creating rules in Outlook through VBA. There is a rule that should apply to all messages, right after they arrive. In a way, there is no condition (this is the difficult part!). I have spent the last hours on MSDN without finding any answer on this. Any idea how to do it?

Also, I am wondering if all messages that arrive can be marked as read. It does not look like it is possible according to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868996.aspx), and I wanted to hear your expert advice on this. I was looking for something like:

```
Dim oRuleNew As Outlook.Rule
Dim oMarkAsReadAction As Outlook.Action
Set oMarkAsReadAction = oRuleNew.Action."mark as un/read type of action"
With oMarkAsReadAction
    .Enabled = True
    .UnRead = False
End With
```

Thank you in advance for your support,

Answer (score 0):

Outlook rules are based on the conditions. There is no conditions in your case. So, consider handling the [NewMailEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff863686(v=office.15).aspx) event of the Application class instead. The event is fired when a new item is received in the Inbox.

Also you may handle the [ItemAdd](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869609(v=office.15).aspx) event of the Items class. The event is fired when one or more items are added to the specified collection. This event does not run when a large number of items are added to the folder at once (more than 16 - this is a known issue).

Comment: Hi Eugene, if I create rule manually, I have an option to apply the rule to all incoming messages. Is there no way to replicate this in VBA?